# jQuery variable claiming it's undefined when it has been defined

Tags: jquery, html, forms, autocomplete

I'm trying to have two autofilling textboxes, one for a phone model - input1 and one for firmware - input2 on the same page. When both filled I want a div to be shown with the ID input1input2, but when entering a value in input1 it claims the variable for phone is undefined, and when filling in the second it claims phoneid is undefined.
Here's the HTML

```
<div id="formcontainer">
<input id="input1"/>
<input id="input2"/>
</div>
<div id="iphone2g1.1" class="info" style="display:none">iPhone 2G</div>
<div id="iphone2g1.2" class="info" style="display:none">iPhone 3G</div>
<div id="iphone2g1.3" class="info" style="display:none">iPhone 3GS</div>
<div id="iphone2g1.4" class="info" style="display:none">iPhone 4</div>
<div id="iphone2g1.5" class="info" style="display:none">iPhone 4S</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#input1").autocompleteArray(["iPhone 2G","iPhone 3G","iPhone 3GS","iPhone 4","iPhone 4s"],
    {   minChars:1,
        matchSubset:1,
        onItemSelect:selectPhone,
        onFindValue:findPhone,
        autoFill:true,
        maxItemsToShow:10,
        selectFirst:true,
    });

$("#input2").autocompleteArray(["1.1","1.2","1.3","1.4","1.5"],
{   minChars:1,
    matchSubset:1,
    onItemSelect:selectFirmware,
    onFindValue:findFirmware,
    autoFill:true,
    maxItemsToShow:10,
    selectFirst:true,
    });

function findPhone(li) {
    if( li == null ) return alert("No match!");
    var phone = li.selectPhone;
    var phoneid = phone.replace("iPhone ","iphone").toLowerCase();
};

function findFirmware(li) {
    if( li == null ) return alert("No match!");
    var firmware = li.selectFirmware;
    $(".info").hide
    $(phoneid+firmware).show
};

function selectPhone(li) {
    findPhone(li);
}

function selectFirmware(li) {
    findFirmware(li);
}
```

I'm using [this](http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-autocomplete.html) for the autocomplete plugin.
The page can be viewed [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3980495/Jailbreak/index.html).

Thanks.

**EDIT1** This is now what the jQuery looks like, but it still throws up the same error.

```
    var phone;
    var phoneid;
    var firmware;
    var firmwareid;

$("#input1").autocompleteArray(["iPhone 2G","iPhone 3G","iPhone 3GS","iPhone 4","iPhone 4s"],
{   minChars:1,
    matchSubset:1,
    onItemSelect:selectPhone,
    onFindValue:findPhone,
    autoFill:true,
    maxItemsToShow:10,
    selectFirst:true,
});

$("#input2").autocompleteArray(["1.1","1.2","1.3","1.4","1.5"],
{   minChars:1,
    matchSubset:1,
    onItemSelect:selectFirmware,
    onFindValue:findFirmware,
    autoFill:true,
    maxItemsToShow:10,
    selectFirst:true,
    });



function findPhone(li) {
    if( li == null ) return alert("No match!");
    phone = li.selectPhone;
    phoneid = phone.replace("iPhone ","iphone").toLowerCase();
};

function findFirmware(li) {
    if( li == null ) return alert("No match!");
    firmware = li.selectFirmware;
    firmwareid = phone.replace(".","");
    $(".info").hide
    $(phoneid+firmware).show
};

function selectPhone(li) {
    findPhone(li);
}

function selectFirmware(li) {
    findFirmware(li);
}
```

Comment: The problem is in the `.` character in id. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names

Comment: @WojciechBednarski I was not aware of this, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the periods in your div's ID attributes and in your `findFirmware()` function, change it to

```
function findFirmware(li) {
    if( li == null ) return alert("No match!");
    firmware = li.selectFirmware;
    firmwareid = phone.replace(".","");
    $(".info").hide();
    $('#' + phoneid + firmwareid).show(); // This line was messed up
};
```

There two problems with this line `$(phoneid+firmware).show`, well four if you count the missing parenthesis and semicolon but...

1. The div your trying to show has an ID, you don't have `#` in your selector to select the element by ID
2. `firmware` contains the unparsed string with the period so `phoneid + firmware` becomes `iphone2g1.2` when your div ID is `iphone2g12` thus you needed to use `firmwareid` in which you parsed it out of.

Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AaNWM/

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a scoping problem. Try adding this to the top of your script:

```
var phone;
var phoneid;
```

The subsequently omit the `var`

```
phone = li.selectPhone;
```

Comment: I have added what you've said to the start and also added firmwareid = phone.replace(".",""); and removed the dots from the IDs but it's still claiming its undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It's not defined anywhere that's accessible to the `findFirmware()` function--it's defined as a `var` in `findPhone()`, hence local to that function.

Not sure what is intended by things like `li.selectFirmware` etc. but those will also break.

Comment: @Supertod You can either make it a global, as Alex suggested, or use one of the JavaScript module patterns to isolate it into a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `.` character in id.

> Basically1, a name must begin with an underscore (_), a dash (-), or a
>   letter(a–z), followed by any number of dashes, underscores, letters,
>   or numbers. There is a catch: if the first character is a dash, the
>   second character must2 be a letter or underscore, and the name must be
>   at least 2 characters long.

[Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names)