# Autocomplete jQuery plugin not working, claiming a variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery variable claiming it's undefined when it has been defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198374/jquery-variable-claiming-its-undefined-when-it-has-been-defined)

The problem is that when opening it in firefox and typing a value for input 1 and selecting it, firebug says that the variable phone isn't defined. I tried defining the variables at the start but it still ceased to work.

This is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var phone;  //fix scoping
var phoneid;
var firmware;
var firmwareid;

$("#input1").autocompleteArray(["iPhone 2G","iPhone 3G","iPhone 3GS","iPhone 4","iPhone 4s"],
{   minChars:1,
    matchSubset:1,
    onItemSelect:selectPhone,
    onFindValue:findPhone,
    autoFill:true,
    maxItemsToShow:10,
    selectFirst:true,
});

$("#input2").autocompleteArray(["1.1","1.2","1.3","1.4","1.5"],
{   minChars:1,
    matchSubset:1,
    onItemSelect:selectFirmware,
    onFindValue:findFirmware,
    autoFill:true,
    maxItemsToShow:10,
    selectFirst:true,
    });



function findPhone(li) {
    if( li == null ) return alert("No match!");
    phone = li.selectPhone;
    phoneid = phone.replace("iPhone ","iphone").toLowerCase();
};

function findFirmware(li) {
    if( li == null ) return alert("No match!");
    firmware = li.selectFirmware;
    firmwareid = phone.replace(".","");
    $(".info").hide
    $(phoneid+firmware).show
};

function selectPhone(li) {
    findPhone(li);
}

function selectFirmware(li) {
    findFirmware(li);
}
    });
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div id="formcontainer">
        <input id="input1"/>
        <input id="input2"/>
</div>
<div id="iphone2g11" class="info" style="display:none">iPhone 2G</div>
<div id="iphone2g12" class="info" style="display:none">iPhone 3G</div>
<div id="iphone2g13" class="info" style="display:none">iPhone 3GS</div>
<div id="iphone2g14" class="info" style="display:none">iPhone 4</div>
<div id="iphone2g15" class="info" style="display:none">iPhone 4S</div>
```

I'm using this plugin for autocomplete http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm

Comment: try moving the var declarations outside of the $(document).ready function.

Comment: @Fosco Nope, still the same error.

Comment: Use autocomplete and not autocompleteArray...

Comment: One thing you should do is remove the comma at the end of your option list; `selectFirst:true,` is the last property being set so the comma technically makes the Javascript invalid and could have side affects depending on what browser your using and its settings.

Comment: I should've mentioned that when the two values have been entered it should reveal the relating div.The autocomplete is working now but it still doesn't reveal the div. This is the error I get when entering the first value. http://cl.ly/3u0h082G1G2I2k281Q07

Comment: Just to add on to my other comment about the extra comma, there's multiple other things here you should fix up in your syntax. **1.)** move your custom functions above the `autocompleteArray()` calls so that the functions are actually defined before being used.  **2.)** `hide`/`show` are methods so you should have the parentheses `hide()`/`show()` and **3.)** you don't have a semicolon at the end of your `hide`/`show` calls...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `findFirmware()` function, change it to

```
function findFirmware(li) {
    if( li == null ) return alert("No match!");
    firmware = li.selectFirmware;
    firmwareid = phone.replace(".","");
    $(".info").hide();
    $('#' + phoneid + firmwareid).show(); // This line was messed up
};
```

There two problems with this line `$(phoneid+firmware).show`, well four if you count the missing parenthesis and semicolon but...

1. The div your trying to show has an ID, you don't have `#` in your selector to select the element by ID
2. `firmware` contains the unparsed string with the period so `phoneid + firmware` becomes `iphone2g1.2` when your div ID is `iphone2g12` thus you needed to use `firmwareid` in which you parsed it out of.

Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AaNWM/

Comment: I love you. Thank you (and everyone else) who have helped me.

Comment: No problem, you should close/delete your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198374/jquery-variable-claiming-its-undefined-when-it-has-been-defined) though as it's a duplicate of this one pretty much... I've gone ahead and posted the same answer in it just in case you can't remove/delete it so you can mark it correct so those who might come across that question instead of this one get the answer also.

Answer (score 2):

Its undefined because you do:

```
li.selectPhone;
```

Which `.selectPhone` doesn't exist on the `li` element passed in. So, once you get to replacing the string, you get an error.

Assuming that I may, possibly, think, that I *might* know what you are trying to do, I changed `li.selectPhone` and `li.selectFirmware` to `li.innerHTML` and it works fine. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLHAX/2/).

**Edit:** You also were using `phone.replace` in your firmware function so I changed that as well in the above fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't seem to reveal the corresponding div.

Answer (score 1):

`phone` is undefined because `li.selectPhone` is undefined.

It's hard to guess why that's missing without seeing autoCompleteArray(), which doesn't seem to be part of the jQuery autocomplete plugin, at first glance?

Comment: `autocompleteArray()` is a part of the plugin, it is a wrapper around the main call. Line `493`: `jQuery.fn.autocompleteArray = function(data, options) {
return this.autocomplete(null, options, data);
} `